# Eclipse WTP Axis 2 Web Service Wizard not creating deployment configuration

Tags: wsdl, apache-axis, eclipse-wtp

I am creating an Axis2 WebService in eclipse in top-down mode using a WSDL file.

I follow the standard steps of new -> other -> WebServices -> Web Service, select Top Down Java Bean Service option, Axis2 as a runtime, Tomcat7 as my server runtime and everything. Then eclipse creates the java class files and configuration files successfully, exept for my service definition inside the WEB-INF/services/ folder.

See attached screenshot:

[image: Project folder structure for WebService definition]

Checking other WebServices created using older versions of eclipse and with other WSDLs, I see that eclipse places inside the /WEB-INF/services/ folder, a folder containing class and configuration files, which I suppose is what makes the Axis2 runtime recognize the service but in my case, when I deploy my web application to the application server, the axis runtime doesn't show my web service listed.

Is this an eclipse/axis2 bug or am I doing something wrong when trying to create my top-down web service?

This is my WSDL file (some names have been changed for privacy reasons):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions name="FooWS" targetNamespace="http://foo.com" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://pagoelectronico.bcr.gob.sv" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://foo.com" version="1.0" xmlns:tns="http://foo.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:element name="sendFoo" type="tns:sendFoo"/>
            <xs:element name="sendFooResponse" type="tns:sendFooResponse"/>
            <xs:complexType name="sendFoo">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="foo" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:complexType name="sendFooResponse">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="sendFoo">
        <part element="tns:sendFoo" name="parameters"/>
    </message>
    <message name="sendFooResponse">
        <part element="tns:sendFooResponse" name="parameters"/>
    </message>
    <portType name="FooEndPoint">
        <operation name="sendFoo">
            <input message="tns:sendFoo"/>
            <output message="tns:sendFooResponse"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="FooWSPortBinding" type="tns:FooEndPoint">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <operation name="sendFoo">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="FooWS">
        <port binding="tns:FooWSPortBinding" name="FooWSPort">
            <soap:address location="http://192.168.11.112:7010/wsPElectronico/FooWS"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

I am using:

- Eclipse Mars (4.5.1) for Windows 64 bits
- Axis 2-1.6.3 runtime
- Apache Tomcat 7.0.12

Comment: I don't think Eclipse 4.5 has bug in this case. I have been do something like this successful. This link may be helpful: http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/TopDownAxis2WebService/td_tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks @dovy, I tried also the steps in that tutorial but I got the same results.